# Deleting all rows from INNER JOINed 3 different tables

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, query-performance

I have a query. I would like to delete all selected rows in these 3 different tables 
Since I have a lot of INNER joins, I couldn't figure it out.
My goal is to delete everything for these seller_ids.

```
SELECT *
FROM orders a
 INNER JOIN order_items b ON a.order_id = b.order_id
 INNER JOIN order_item_histories c ON c.order_item_id = b.order_item_id
WHERE a.seller_id IN (1, 3)
```

Version Postgres 10.3

I tried this but I couldn't succeed.

```
DELETE
FROM  
   USING orders
   USING order_items,
   USING order_item_histories
WHERE orders.order_id = order_items.order_id AND order_items.order_item_id = order_item_histories.order_item_id
AND  orders.seller_id IN (1, 3)
```

Comment: on delete cascade?

Comment: @lmanol Y.
Unfortunately I don't have foreign keys among these tables. There are some reasons for that so that I am looking for a way around.

Comment: Are the `INNER` joins intentional or you meant to write `LEFT` joins? In other words, do you want to delete from table `a` only when it has related rows in tables `b` and `c`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ When all 3 tables and conditionmatches, I want to delete all matched from all 3. So that if only matches in orders table doesn't work for. It must match condition in 3 of them at once.

Comment: So you mean that if there are orders for say seller 1 but no order_items or orders and order_items but no order_items_histories, then you don't want to delete anything?

Comment: Exactly, all conditions must be matched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DELETE` statement can only delete from one table (unless there are triggers or foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE` options defined).

To overcome the problem you can either use 3 `DELETE` statements:

```
DELETE FROM order_item_histories
WHERE order_item_id IN
      ( SELECT b.order_item_id 
        FROM order_items AS b
             JOIN orders AS a
               ON a.order_id = b.order_id
        WHERE a.seller_id IN (1, 3)
      )
RETURNING order_item_id, order_item_history_id ;

DELETE FROM order_items 
WHERE order_id IN 
      ( SELECT order_id
        FROM orders
        WHERE seller_id IN (1, 3)
      )
RETURNING order_id, order_item_id ;

DELETE FROM orders
WHERE seller_id IN (1, 3)
RETURNING order_id ;
```

or by chaining (data modifying) CTEs:

```
WITH 
  a AS 
  ( DELETE FROM orders
    WHERE seller_id IN (1, 3)
    RETURNING order_id
  ),
  b AS
  ( DELETE FROM order_items 
    WHERE order_id IN (SELECT order_id FROM a)
    RETURNING order_id, order_item_id 
  ),
  c AS
  ( DELETE FROM order_item_histories
    WHERE order_item_id IN (SELECT order_item_id FROM b)
    RETURNING order_item_id, order_item_history_id
  )
SELECT
    a.order_id,
    b.order_item_id, 
    c.order_item_history_id
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b ON a.order_id = b.order_id
  LEFT JOIN c ON c.order_item_id = b.order_item_id ;
```

Comment: I commented on the first post. Can you please check it makes any difference with this SQL? Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

If you have more than one join you could use comma separated USING statements:

```
DELETE 
FROM 
      AAA AS a 
USING 
      BBB AS b,
      CCC AS c
WHERE 
      a.id = b.id 
  AND a.id = c.id
  AND a.uid = 12345 
  AND c.gid = 's434sd4'
```

[Reference](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/guidelines-for-sql/writing-code-compliant-with-both-mysql-and-postgresql/mysqlism-and-0)

Comment: Probably not selected as the answer because this doesn't delete from all three tables, but this approach with 3 different statements would be more elegant

Comment: If you want to delete from multiple tables, add the table name in the from column, and remove that from using table

Comment: This was useful to me as I was looking for multiple joins lol